# Show all dates/days in month and week view of Fullcalendar even if there is no event for that specific date in list view?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am working on the Angular-11 application and using Fullcaledar 5.5.0, I have a requirement to view events in list view (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view), but when I integrate this it shows only those days which have events on it.

Let me explain to you with an example,

I have 2 events one is for Monday and another one is for Friday, so when I see the list view it shows only 2 rows (Monday and Friday). But I want that all days will appear and show events with days that have and the days which don't have events should show no event tag.

Any kind of help is appreciable.

Comment: No that isn't possible currently. See https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features to request it.